# Subquery keeps loading when adding OR statement

Tags: mysql, subquery

I would like to display the top 15 used titles, with the corresponding number of articles behind this. At this point, it's working. However, now I want to add another 'OR statement', this is where the query keeps loading (until I kill it manually).

Working query:

```
SELECT
    title,
    title as t,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM articles WHERE title = t) as nr
FROM
    articles
GROUP BY
    title
ORDER BY
    nr DESC
LIMIT
    15
```

Failing query:

```
SELECT
    title,
    title as t,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM articles WHERE title = t OR title = 'Example title') as nr
FROM
    articles
GROUP BY
    title
ORDER BY
    nr DESC
LIMIT
    15
```

Anybody an idea why this query is failing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the second `OR` and why are you introducing it to a correlated subquery?

Comment: @peterm It's for a searchbar where you will be able to select multiple titles to filter on. So when not selected any title, you will see the number of articles with the title, behind these title's names. But after this selection, behind every title, you will see the total number of items of the item displayed AND the items clicked before. So it will give you a preview of how many articles the search will display after clicking this title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
title,
title as jt,
(SELECT count(id) FROM articles WHERE (title = t OR title = 'Example title')) as nr
FROM
articles
GROUP BY
title
ORDER BY
nr DESC
LIMIT
15
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a self-join would do you a better job than a columnar ( select count()) call which is executed every time for every row.

```
SELECT
      A1.title,
      count( A2.ID ) as NR
   FROM
      articles A1
         JOIN articles A2
            on A1.title = A2.title
   GROUP BY
      A1.title
   ORDER BY
      NR DESC
   LIMIT
      15
```

Now, to implement your "OR" condition.  I think what is killing what you have is that the "OR" is applied to ALL titles, so you are counting that for every entry and getting the same PLUS whatever it was already getting from it's own title match.

What I THINK you really mean is you want this as a filter (WHERE criteria).  That you want all articles that are like "Example title", and from those articles how many articles were associated with their "title" content being the same.  If this is the case, just add to the above query...

```
WHERE
   A1.title = 'Example title'
```

Example... your articles table has titles like

```
Example SQL
Example Query MySQL
Example Query SQL-Server
Example I dont care
Example Query Oracle
Example Query Oracle 11
Example Query SQL-Server 2008
```

So if you were looking for a title like "Example Query", you would get the entries back for MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, Oracle 11, SQL-Server 2008 and completely ignore the ones of SQL and 'I dont care'.  Does this make sense to the context you are trying to get?

Comment: Thanks for your try, however this is not exactly what i'm looking for. Maybe this title example is not the best example. Let's say instead of titles, we use categories.

So, in my first search I select cat#1, which has 500 articles connected. Now I need to see all other categories, with the corresponding nr of articles behind them. However, clicking the category (example cat#2), will show me the results of cat#1 (500) PLUS the results of of cat#2 (let's say 200). So total is 700 articles. This number, 700, is what i want to predict/show behind all category names before clicking it.

Comment: @DiegoVoors, I would edit your existing post, revise the title to better reflect that and then provide some samples of the data you want to get out... even if you show in a hierarchy simulation... Don't use tabs for layout, but spaces as tabs dont format well.  Then block it with the curly brackets for easier readability.  You might get better answers closer to your needs.